# mmap with direct IO

Tags: c, memory-management, file-io, io, mmap

my doubt is,

1. If I enables the IO buffer then mmaps shows better IOPS and less latency, why this is happening and what is the relation.
2. Secondly, when the IO buffer is disabled, there is no value  upto block size 4kb i.e. no values when block size is 512b, 1k & 2k, what is happening, Is it anything related to page size ( usually page size is 4kb and mmap operates in count of pages)

I am using Flexible IO (fio) for benchmark the system. I have a confusion regarding using Direct IO with mmap (IO Engine). As per my understanding mmap uses the process space to create a virtual address mapping to the file and IO buffer enable to use the memory instead of direct IO.

I searched a lot but it's not clear, can somebody explain to me please ...